# Maven dependency for Tableau Data Extractor API?

Tags: java, maven, tableau-api

I am trying to create a maven dependency to use the Tableau Data Extractor API. I have followed the suggestions here https://community.tableau.com/thread/172839 as I cant find any official documentation

I download and extract the API here https://www.tableau.com/data-extract-api.
and follow the suggestions

The above post suggests running the following commands

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jna.jar -DgroupId=com.sun.jna -DartifactId=jna -Dversion=3.5.1 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=tableauextract.jar -DgroupId=com.tableausoftware -DartifactId=tableau-extract -Dversion=9.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=tableaucommon.jar -DgroupId=com.tableausoftware -DartifactId=tableau-common -Dversion=9.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=tableauserver.jar -DgroupId=com.tableausoftware -DartifactId=tableau-server -Dversion=9.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then add dependencies to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tableausoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>tableau-extract</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tableausoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>tableau-common</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tableausoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>tableau-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I am not very familiar with maven and probably wrong, but i think the API has been updated and now contains only these 2 jars instead of the 4 above

dataextract.jar
jna.jar

I dont see any reference to the tableaucommon or tableauserver jars. Does anyone know if they are still needed, where can I get them?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the JNA dependency, as JNA is actually available on maven central.

Comment: Anything about the other two, tableau-common abd tableau-server? Do you know if they are available?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about tableau, and I can't help you with that.

Comment: The extract API has been rolled into the Tableau SDK.  I followed the download instructions on this page: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_installing.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____3  In the downloaded zip file I found tableaucommon.jar and tableauextract.jar

Comment: I also had to add to my windows PATH environment variable the bin folder from the extracted zip file